# autoincremento do mysql reinicia sozinho

Tags: php, mysql

estou com o mesmo problema descrito aqui neste link:
http://forum.novosga.org/discussion/26/erro-ao-reiniciar-a-senhas

a orientação dada foi fazer isso aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823877/how-to-prevent-mysql-from-resetting-auto-increment-value

mas eu não entendi bem, alguém poderia me explicar a solução dada neste segundo link?

Answer (score 1):

Ali explica que [TRUNCATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/truncate-table.html) reseta os campos AutoIncrement da tabela, e que [DELET FROM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html) não reseta os campos, mesmo você apagando a linha que contenha o maior valor AutoIncrement não será resetado!

Revise seus códigos você pode estar usando o Truncate!

Answer (score 1):

**Comparando TRUNCATE TABLE:**

> Qualquer valor AUTO_INCREMENT é resetado para o seu valor inicial. Isso vale tanto para MyISAM como para InnoDB, o que normalmente não ocorre com valores de seqüência. [DELETE FROM TABELA ...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html)
>
> Se você excluir o registro que contiver a ID máxima "MAX(ID)", sendo ela uma coluna AUTO_INCREMENT, o valor não será mais atualizado, tanto para MyISAM como para InnoDB. Agora, se você excluir todos os registros da tabela, com DELETE FROM TABELA (sem usar a cláusula WHERE) com o modo de confirmação automática, a sequência será reiniciada em todos os mecanismos de armazenamento InnoDB, com exceção de tabelas MyISAM. Há algumas exceções para esse comportamento para tabelas InnoDB, como discutido na [Seção 13.3.5.3](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/lock-tables-restrictions.html), "Manutenção de AUTO_INCREMENT para InnoDB".
>
> Para tabelas MyISAM, você pode definir uma nova coluna AUTO_INCREMENT secundária com uma chave do tipo multiple-column. Dessa maneira, poderá reutilizar os valores eliminados a partir do início da sequência. Veja na [Seção 3.6.9](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-auto-increment.html), "Uso do AUTO_INCREMENT".